# Can I put my docker repository/image on GitHub/Bitbucket?

Tags: docker

I know that Docker hub is there but it allows only for 1 private repository. Can I put these images on Github/Bitbucket?

Comment: Do you mean putting the `Dockerfile` or the complete image? `Dockerfile` is text and should be in a repository. But if you are wanting to put the complete image in a Github repo, that would be a very bad practice.

Comment: This is officially supported on GitHub with the new "**GitHub Container Registry**". See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63693229/6309).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In general you don't want to use version control on large binary images (like  videos or compiled files) as git and such was intended for 'source control', emphasis on the **source**.  Technically, here's nothing preventing you from doing so and putting the docker image files into git (outside the limits of the service you're using).

One major issue you'll have is git/bitubucket have no integration with Docker as neither provide the Docker Registry api needed for a docker host to be able to pull down the images as needed.  This means you'll need to manually pull down out of the version control system holding the image files if you want to use it.

If you're going to do that, why not just use S3 or something like that?

If you really want 'version control' on your images (which docker hub does not do...) you'd need to look at something like: https://about.gitlab.com/2015/02/17/gitlab-annex-solves-the-problem-of-versioning-large-binaries-with-git/

Finally, docker hub only allows one *FREE* private repo.  You can pay for more.

Comment: I think a lot of developers are trying to use git repos as a cure-all to their dependency storage needs. I think it stems from a need for simplicity. I realize that git shouldn't be used for large objects, but it sure would be easier if I could just keep all dependencies/assets in one place. I think in the future some services might offer features akin to an webdrive, just as bitbucket offers a wiki.

Comment: Why is the recommender systems textbook link (http://www.kdnuggets.com/2016/04/recommender-systems-textbook.html) in the answer? It does not have any references to git / github / source control / Docker.

Comment: @PulkitAgarwal never noticed this, must have mistakenly pasted the wrong link when creating the post.

Answer (score 5):

So the way to go is:

1. Create a repository on Github or Bitbucket
2. Commit and push your Dockerfile (with config files if necessary)
3. Create an automated build on Docker Hub which uses the Github / Bitbucket repo as source.

In case you need it all private you can self-host a git service like [Gitlab](https://about.gitlab.com/) or [GOGS](https://gogs.io/) and of course you can also selfhost a [docker registry service](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/) for the images.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, since Sept. 2020.

See "[**Introducing GitHub Container Registry**](https://github.blog/2020-09-01-introducing-github-container-registry/)" from **[Kayla Ngan](https://github.com/kaylangan)**:

> Since releasing [GitHub Packages last year](https://github.blog/2019-05-10-introducing-github-package-registry/) (May 2019), hundreds of millions of packages have been downloaded from GitHub, with Docker as the second most popular ecosystem in Packages behind npm.
>
> Available today as a public beta, GitHub Container Registry improves how we handle containers within GitHub Packages.
> With the new capabilities introduced today, you can better enforce access policies, encourage usage of a standard base image, and promote innersourcing through easier sharing across the organization.

[image: https://github.blog/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/package-registry.png]

> Our users have asked for anonymous access for public container images, similar to how we enable anonymous access to public repositories of source code today.
> Anonymous access is available with GitHub Container Registry today, and we’ve gotten things started today by publishing a public image of our own super-linter.
> **GitHub Container Registry is free for public images.**
>
> With [GitHub Actions, publishing to GitHub Container Registry is easy](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/publish-docker). Actions automatically suggests workflows based for you based on your work, and we’ve updated the “Publish Docker Container” workflow template to make publishing straightforward.

[image: https://github.blog/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/workflow.png?resize=1024%2C902?w=1024]

Answer (score 3):

GitHub is in the process of releasing something similar to ECR or Docker Hub. At the time of writing this, it's in Alpha phase and you can request access.

From GitHub:

> "GitHub Package Registry is a software package hosting service, similar to npmjs.org, rubygems.org, or hub.docker.com, that allows you to host your packages and code in one place. You can host software packages privately or publicly and use them as dependencies in your projects."

https://help.github.com/en/articles/about-github-package-registry

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are saying about docker images. You can setup your own [private registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/) which will contain the docker images. If you are not pushing only dockerfiles, but are interested in pushing the whole image, then pushing the images as a whole to github is a very bad idea. Consider a case you have 600 MB of docker image, pushing it to github is like putting 600 MB of data to a github repo, and if you keep on pushing more images there, it will get terribly bad.

Also, docker registry does the intelligent mapping of storing only a single copy of a layer (this layer can be referenced by multiple images). If you use github, you are not going to use this use-case. You will end up storing multiple copies of large files which is really really bad.

I would definitely suggest you to go with a private docker registry rather than going with github.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a real need of putting docker image to github/bitbucket you can try to save it into archive (by using https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/) and commit/push it to your repository.